# django rest api call admin action

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i created a simple model and created an admin action for it. Then i installed dango-rest and connected to model so i can use it from another machine with rest api calls. Is there a way i can call the admin action as well?

Here is my sample:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class my_model(models.Model):
    my_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True, max_length=20)
    my_line = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='#')
    my_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin, messages
from .models import my_model

def precheck_action(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for obj in queryset:
        if obj.my_line == 'second step':
            obj.my_description = 'provided'
        else:
            obj.my_description = 'waithing for second step'
        obj.save()

class my_form((forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = int_unmanaged

        fields = '__all__'

class my_form_admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = my_form
    list_display = ('my_id', 'my_line','my_description')
    actions = [precheck_action]
admin.site.register(my_form, my_form_admin)
```

Any help on solving this or maybe a better way of doing it would be great.

Thank!

Comment: You can just call the action function from your app view

Comment: Somethimg like import admin, and then admin.function() ? How will i create a call to that function? do i have to create a separate view for this? can you please provide me an example. THX!